# python try except with different action

Tags: python

I am making REST API calls to populate inventory of all our devices. The API returns multiple layers of nested dictionary + lists where some keys are missing for certain types devices.

I am trying to loop through our whole inventory and store each of the values in a list or 'n/a' if not found. Code thrown an exception if the that device's dictionary does not contain the specific key. These lists will be used to create a Panda df.

I ended up using multiple try-except blocks since I need a different action based on the line that caused the exception. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
def populate_list(device_id, device_model, device_sn, result):
    for items in result:
        try:        
            device_id.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['@id'])
        except:
            device_id.append('n/a')            
        try:
            device_model.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['summary']['deviceType'])
        except:
            device_model.append('n/a')
       try:
            device_sn.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['chassis']['chassis'][0]['serialNr'])
        except:
            device_sn.append('n/a')
```

Comment: Because keys aren't repeated, I cannot see any improvement  to your current code, either in readability or performance.

Comment: You may want to add `pass` on the `except` block otherwise it will break the `for`loop on first error.

Comment: And finally, your question doesn't belong on stackoverflow, post it on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: deleted my answer - it's not clear what's needed here

Comment: Side-note: Don't use bare `except:` blocks. Now receiving a Ctrl-C (which raises `KeyboardInterrupt`) gets ignored and the code acts as if lookup failed. For code like this, you almost certainly want `except KeyError:` (maybe `TypeError` as well, if you want to handle some values being `dict` or non-`dict`), which only handles missing keys (which you expect), rather than silently ignoring all sorts of other possible errors you didn't anticipate and acting like they were ones you expected.

Comment: You should only catch KeyError: `except KeyError` and if you know only the last key will be missing you can try smth like ` device_id.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO'].get('@id', 'n/a'))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could enclose the logic into a method. See example below:

```
def get_value(source, keys):
       value = 'n/a'
       try:
            x = source[0]
            for idx in range(1, len(keys)):
                  x = x[keys[idx]]
            value = x
        except:
            print("Failed to retrieve value - will return {}".format(value))
        return value

def populate_list(device_id, device_model, device_sn, result):
    for items in result:
        device_id.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO','@id']))
        device_model.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO', 'summary', 'deviceType']))
        device_sn.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO', 'chassis', 'chassis', 0, 'serialNr']))
```

Comment: Should be `get_value(device_id,...`, `get_value(device_model,...`, then `get_value(device_sn,...`

Comment: But this example is wrong, since OP wants to read from `items['keys']` not `device_id['keys']`

Comment: This is a better answer and this can be improved by actually having a reference dict of the device attribute and the path in the result where the value can be found. That way you are not hardcoding the list in the for loop. For ex:
`ref_dict["device_id"] = ['inventoryDetailsDTO', '@id']`
On that note @eten - you should consider passing a dict containing the attributes you care for instead of passing them individually. That may not be maintainable.

Comment: Test your code. The `get_value` method will not actually modify `device_id`, `device_model` etc. You should return `value`, and then in `populate_list` do `device_id.append(get_value(items,['keys']))`

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the bugs. Thank you for pointing them out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afk right now; I'll add a more complete answer later.
In synthesis: try to see if it comes in handy to declare exception as car

```
Try:
    my_code_to_check
Except (ExceptionName, AnotherExceptionName,...) as e:
    """Perform actions"""
```

Try to check it out if you can get a var for every exception and/or a an if statement (or dict + get method) for every possible error

UPDATE:
sorry, I was driving and my reply wasn't indeed very related to the topic.
Now I made some "experiment":

```
import time

#orignal method
def populate_list(device_id, device_model, device_sn, result):
    for items in result:
        try:
            device_id.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['@id'])
        except:
            device_id.append('n/a')
        try:
            device_model.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['summary']['deviceType'])
        except:
            device_model.append('n/a')
        try:
            device_sn.append(items['inventoryDetailsDTO']['chassis']['chassis'][0]['serialNr'])
        except:
            device_sn.append('n/a')

        return device_id, device_model, device_sn


# second method
def get_value(source, keys):
    value = 'n/a'
    try:
        x = source[0]
        for idx in range(1, len(keys)):
            x = x[keys[idx]]
        value = x
    except KeyError:
        print("Failed to retrieve value - will return {}".format(value))
    return value


def populate_list_2(device_id, device_model, device_sn, result):
    for items in result:
        device_id.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO', '@id']))
        device_model.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO', 'summary', 'deviceType']))
        device_sn.append(get_value(items, ['inventoryDetailsDTO', 'chassis', 'chassis', 0, 'serialNr']))

        return device_id, device_model, device_sn


#third method
def populate_list_3(device_id, device_model, device_sn, result):
    for items in result:

        device_id.append(items.get('inventoryDetailsDTO', {}).get('@id', "n/a"))
        device_model.append(items.get('inventoryDetailsDTO', {}).get('summary', {}).get('deviceType', "n/a"))
        device_sn.append(items.get('inventoryDetailsDTO', {}).get('chassis', {}).get('chassis', {}).get(0, {}).get('serialNr', "n/a"))

        return device_id, device_model, device_sn


if __name__ == "__main__":

    d1 = {"inventoryDetailsDTO": {'@id': "got it"}, "casual": "a value", "foo": "april's foo"}
    d2 = {"check": 2, "dunno": "wow", 4: 10}
    d3 = {"check": 3, "dict": {"inside": {"another": "450909"}}}
    list_of_dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
    device_id = []
    device_model = []
    device_sn = []
    start = time.time()
    device_id, device_model, device_sn = populate_list(device_id, device_model, device_sn, list_of_dicts)
    end = time.time()
    print("first way")
    print(end-start, "\nresult:", device_id, device_model, device_sn, "\n")

    # reset and go with second method
    d1 = {"inventoryDetailsDTO": {'@id': "got it"}, "casual": "a value",  "foo": "april's foo"}
    d2 = {"check": 2, "dunno": "wow", 4: 10}
    d3 = {"check": 3, "dict": {"inside": {"another": "450909"}}}
    list_of_dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
    device_id = []
    device_model = []
    device_sn = []
    start = time.time()
    device_id, device_model, device_sn = populate_list_2(device_id, device_model, device_sn, list_of_dicts)
    end = time.time()
    print("second way")
    print(end - start, "\nresult:", device_id, device_model, device_sn, "\n")

    # reset and go with third way
    d1 = {"inventoryDetailsDTO": {'@id': "got it"}, "casual": "a value", "foo": "april's foo"}
    d2 = {"check": 2, "dunno": "wow", 4: 10}
    d3 = {"check": 3, "dict": {"inside": {"another": "450909"}}}
    list_of_dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
    device_id = []
    device_model = []
    device_sn = []
    start = time.time()
    device_id, device_model, device_sn = populate_list_3(device_id, device_model, device_sn, list_of_dicts)
   end = time.time()
   print("third way")
   print(end - start, "\nresult:", device_id, device_model, device_sn, "\n")
```

I implemented three different methods and also tracked the time needed in the performance.

here's the result:

first way

4.0531158447265625e-06

['got it'] ['n/a'] ['n/a']

second way

Failed to retrieve value - will return n/a

Failed to retrieve value - will return n/a

Failed to retrieve value - will return n/a

1.4781951904296875e-05

['n/a'] ['n/a'] ['n/a']

third way

2.86102294921875e-06 -> best speed with nested dict.get() method

['got it'] ['n/a'] ['n/a']

I tested the functions only trying to emulate a possible "positive result" for the first dictionary you listed.
I'ven't tested it more

Hope it helps

Comment: assuming the incoming args are all lists, the only potential exception raised here would be a `KeyError`

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right!

Comment: I updated the answer, now it should be meaningful